# How to use a external JSON file instead of a hard coded JSON file in the HTML?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, charts, visualization

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

            path {
                stroke: steelblue;
                stroke-width: 1;
                fill: none;
            }

            .axis {
              shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .x.axis line {

            }

            .x.axis .minor {
              stroke-opacity: .5;
            }

            .x.axis path {
              display: none;
            }

            .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #000;
            }
</style>
<div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
        var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
        var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

        var data = [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7];
```

This is using a JSON file inside the html code which is quite understandable but if I wants to use an external JSON file that is in the same file directory of the HTML page, what method do I need to change for it to read the JSON file from the file directory instead of using the var data method above?

```
        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h, 0]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d,i) { 
                console.log('Plotting X value for data point: ' + d + ' using index: ' + i + ' to be at: ' + x(i) + ' using our xScale.');
                return x(i); 
            })
            .y(function(d) { 
                console.log('Plotting Y value for data point: ' + d + ' to be at: ' + y(d) + " using our yScale.");
                return y(d); 
            })

            var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
                  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);

            graph.append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                  .call(xAxis);

            var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");

            graph.append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
                  .call(yAxisLeft);

            graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
</script>
</div>
```

The below is the JSON file that I would like to read from the file directory whereas the x-axis of the graph will be the year and the y-axis of the graph will be the cases.

```
[{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1960","cases":"887"},{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1965","cases":"218"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either include the json file in the html by

```
<script src="thejsonFile.js"></script>
```

And the json file

```
var jsonObject = [{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1960","cases":"887"},{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1965","cases":"218"}];
```

And use `jsonObject` in your functions.

Or you can call it by ajax

```
$.get('thejsonFile.js', function(data){
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
  //then your functions
});
```

Where the `thejsonFile.js` should be like

```
[{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1960","cases":"887"},{"countryName":"Afghanistan","year":"1965","cases":"218"}];
//without declaration.
```

Comment: Is there any way such as d3.json("data.json", type, function(error, data) {};

Comment: Yes, you can try, but I think most likely as `d3.json("data.json", function(data){});`